# Why my Restangular object is empty?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm creating a small app. I need github emoji's to be loaded in it. I'm using restangular for it.
I've set restangular baseUrl as:

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://api.github.com');
```

What I need is now I want to get some emoji's which I have defined in a array. Which is:

```
$scope.emojiNames = ['tokyo_tower', 'tongue', 'tractor', 'traffic_light', 'train', 'tiger', 'red_car'];

    $scope.emojisObj = Restangular.one("emojis").get().
    then(function(res) {
        return ($scope.emojiNames).map(function(emoji) {
            return res[emoji];

         }, function(err) {
            console.log("ERR:", err);
        });
    });
```

While consoling `emojisObj`, it is showing respective URL values.

But while binding `emojisObj` in Html it is showing as an empty. Where did I do mistake?

My Html code is:

```
<span ng-repeat="emoji in emojisObj track by $index">
    <img ng-src="{{emoji}}" height="100px" width="100px"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant return from inside promise. What are you doing here is that you are returning Restangular.one().get to $scope if you want to unmap the response it should be done like thi

```
Restangular.one("emojis").get().then(function(res) {
    var mapped = [];
    $scope.emojiNames).map(function(emoji) {
        mapped.push(res[emoji]);
    });
    $scope.emojisObj = mapped;

}, function(err) {
        console.log("ERR:", err);
});
```

Or directly

```
Restangular.one("emojis").get().then(function(res) {
    $scope.emojisObj = [];
    $scope.emojiNames).map(function(emoji) {
        $scope.emojisObj.push(res[emoji]);
    });

}, function(err) {
        console.log("ERR:", err);
});
```